# Crystal Reports 10 sort by formula field

Tags: crystal-reports

can anyone please help me with this? I am trying to sort my report by a formula field i created but since it's a formula field it doesn't show on record sort expert.

is there a way to do this? thanks alot

Comment: Please post the formula's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always have the sort be performed on the server and then select to keep the original sort order in the grouping expert.